# Loading page while waiting for API response

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to enhance a page that will display a list of data (1 - 100k).

The enhancement that I am trying to make is to change the status of that list of data.

Steps for simulation:

1. User search list of data
2. List of data displayed out in a gridview
3. User select 100 data in the list to change the status form active to expired
4. System auto refresh page to display the updated list

At the 3rd step, I will be passing the request to a PUT API to help me update the status in the database.

While waiting for it to load, is there a way for me to display a loading page after the user send the request?

This is my current code:

```
protected void btnUpdateSelectedItem(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        MyAPI myAPI = new MyAPI();
        var result = myAPI.UpdateStatus(request);
        // create a loading page while the result did not return anything
        RefreshPage();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.Error(ex);
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Unexpected error happened, please contact system administrator.')", true);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you tag this with ASP.NET Core when you're clearly using WebForms? (And why are you using WebForms in 2021?!?!)

Comment: how are u sending the PUT request ? 
is it using javascript (ajax )or ? normal post method to a controller ?

Comment: WebForms _does_ support `async` operations - but with huge caveats (e.g. you can't use `async` methods from within WebForms server-side event-handlers like your `btnUpdateSelectedItem` method), see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45 - you also need to set `Async="True"` in your `<%@ Page` directive.

Comment: @IbraHimM.Nada i send using URL

Comment: @Dai I removed the ASP.NET Core tag. This is an enhancement only. This project existed for quite some time already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't need to do anything special here.

> User select 100 data in the list to change the status form active to expired

Sure, add a check box row to the grid you display - no problem.

> System auto refresh page to display the updated list

Ohhh? What do you mean here? The system does not auto update anything here. You on the step of the user selecting + checking + choosing rows. So far so good, so far so simple.

Obvious, then when the user is done selecting, they hit a button "process" or "update" or "submit" or whatever. that simple buttion click is WHEN you update the display to "Processing - please" wait. So there not some magic out of the blue update process here, but ONLY a process that starts when the user is good and ready and is DONE selecting the rows/data to process.

To display some "wait while processing" message? Just simple attach a client side script to the server side (plane jane asp.net button) you dropped into that form.

Say we have this form:

However, lets assume we have this grid - nothing fancy:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GVHotels" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
     DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table">
     <Columns>
       <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName"   HeaderText="FirstName" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName"    HeaderText="LastName"  />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="City"        HeaderText="City" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName"   HeaderText="HotelName" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description"  />

       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="To Process" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
         <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSel" runat="server" CssClass="bigcheck"/>
         </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
<asp:Button ID="cmdProcess" runat="server" Text="Process selected" CssClass="btn" />
            <br />
```

And code to fill grid is:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from tblHotels ORDER BY HotelName",
            new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST3)))
        {
            cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
            GVHotels.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader();
            GVHotels.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Ok, we now have this:

[image]

So user is free to check off each row for processing.

The "process records" can be this:

```
protected void cmdProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string strIDList = "";
foreach (GridViewRow gRow in GVHotels.Rows)
{
    CheckBox ckSel = (CheckBox)gRow.FindControl("chkSel");
    if (ckSel.Checked)
    {
        int pkID = (int)GVHotels.DataKeys[gRow.RowIndex]["ID"];
        if (strIDList != "")
            strIDList += ",";
        strIDList += pkID.ToString();
    }
}

// now data process selected list
DataTable rstToProcess = new DataTable();

string strSQL = "SELECT * from tblHotels where ID IN (" + strIDList + ")";
using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL,
        new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST3)))
{
    cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL);
    SqlCommandBuilder daU = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);

    rstToProcess.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            
    // now process each row
    foreach (DataRow dRow in rstToProcess.Rows)
    {
        dRow["Active"] = true;
        dRow["Rating"] = 2;
    }
    // now send all process data back to database
    da.Update(rstToProcess);
}
// show updated grid
LoadGrid();
}
```

so I really don't see the problem. If you want a "please process message"? then just add a client side routine to the button click.

eg: this:

```
    <asp:Button ID="cmdProcess" runat="server" 
      Text="Process selected" CssClass="btn" 
        OnClick="cmdProcess_Click"
        OnClientClick="mywaitmsg();return true;" />
```

So, now we have in js code say this:

```
  <script>
    function mywaitmsg() {
      $('#GHotels').hide()
      $('#MyCoolGifDiv').show()
     }
```

So above will simple hide the grid, display that cool "div" with a please wait while processing message, and probably a cool "gif" spinner or some such.

Comment: Hi Albert, first of all thanks for the reply. I wish to do this loading gif is because when I click on the submit button, it will load and because the API did not have time to response back and it cause my web to create session timeout. 
So far this method helped me, but I will need to do a load test just to be sure.
Thanks alot!!

Comment: as noted, you don't necessary have to hide the "grid div" as per above, but by adding a client side click event to the button, then you can easy turn on the animated gif, or some please wait working message. I do this all the time and it works great. As noted, even better since when code behind is done, then the fresh new page from the server finally does make the trip back client side, and that re-sets your div that displayed the animated gif for you without needing extra code to hide that animated gif.